# Can I get the webServer's name when a host header is set (IIS, asp.Net)

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, dns, hostheaders

Is it possible to find what the Web Server's name is when the host header is set to something else in an asp.net web app? Environment is a company intranet, Windows 2003 server (IIS 6).

e.g.  the host header may be set to   myApp.company.com   and the servers name might be webAppServer1.company.com or webAppServer2.company.com

Using the Server Variable "SERVER_NAME" just returns the host header...

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
string host = Environment.MachineName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, this I presume accesses the same information as Wim Hollebrandse's suggestion:

```
My.Computer.Name
```

Comment: Yep. It's exactly the same. The Computer object lives in Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices and inherits from ServerComputer which implements it's Name getter property by returning Environment.MachineName.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is using: `Server.MachineName`